# Power Automate: How to extract user that sends a teams message?

Tags: automation, power-automate

I need to extract from the trigger "When keywords are mentioned" on microsoft teams the user that triggered the flow.
This ideally would be the email of the user.

How can I get this information and store it in a variable? It does not appear to be available as a dynamic option.

Sorry really struggling to find any documentation on this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Zack

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7ERp.png)

Tried using TriggerOutputs()?['headers']?['From'] as the value, generated from asking CHATGPT the question.
No result produced.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a `Get message detais` action after it, to get it. See below:

[image]

Comment: Did this answer your question?